# file name with special characters like "é" NOT FOUND

Tags: php, file, url, unicode, filenames

I have a folder on my website just for random files. I used php opendir to list all the files so i can style the page a bit. But the files that I uploaded with special characters in them don't work. when i click on them it says the files are not found. but when i check the directory, the files are there. seems like the links are wrong. any idea how i can get a correct link to these file names with special characters in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky. It depends what encoding your filesystem uses for filenames and how (if) your webserver or PHP functions convert the encoding.

First of all, make sure your links *never* use unencoded non-ASCII characters. URLs should be in UTF-8, i.e. é should be encoded as %C3%A9. If that doesn't work, try %E9 (é in ISO-8859-1).

You might find `iconv()` function useful to convert encodings. `rawurlencode()` is obligatory.

Comment: i tried:

print('<li><span class="count">' . $count . '.</span> <a href="/files/' . iconv_set_encoding($file, "UTF-8") . '">' . iconv_set_encoding($file, "UTF-8") .'</a></li>' . "\n");

But the links are now just all empty, like this: <a href="/files/"></a></li>

Answer (score 0):

do you see them if you run this?

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/folder') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

EDIT: just realised i misread the question. Its likely some kind of encoding issue like porneL says